# Rotating an avplayer video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

As the question states, is there any way of rotating a video in avplayer.

Currently, I'm presenting a class that is an instance of avplayercontroller modally. The entire app runs only in portrait mode but I want this video to be played in landscape mode.

I've already tried the "shouldAutorotate" and other methods listed here:
[Only ONE VIEW landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928057/xcode-only-one-view-landscape-mode)

Swift just doesn't seem to like allowing modally presented view controllers to be a different orientation.

Code for how my video controller class

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class streamStuffViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

     var isPresented = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: currentStream))
        self.player.play()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        self.player.pause()
    }


}
```

Comment: @RaymondRangel, Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
        if navigationController.visibleViewController is PlayVideoViewController {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
        } else {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
        }
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}
```

If your application works only in potrait mode but you want just avplayer to rotate then add this code to AppDelegate.swift file and replace  'PlayVideoViewController' with your ControllerName.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same situation just a while ago. I too tried to change the orientation only one screen and i did it with a hack i added
`self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.5708)` this line in `viewDidLoad()` to rotate the whole view. But Still you will see the carrier and battery symbol in the portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm listening to orientation change:

```
// view did load
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceOrientationDidChange), name: .UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
```

Then I rotate the video player but only to landscape left/right in my scenario:

```
@objc func deviceOrientationDidChange() {          
  switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
  case .faceUp, .faceDown, .portrait, .unknown, .portraitUpsideDown:
    // default the player to original rotation
    self.playerController.view.transform = .identity 
    self.playerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)

  case .landscapeLeft:
    self.playerController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat((90 * Double.pi)/180))
    self.playerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)

  case .landscapeRight:
    self.playerController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat((-90 * Double.pi)/180))
    self.playerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
  }
}
```

You can wrap that code inside `UIView.animate` if you are into animations.

Don't forget to call `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` on `deinit()`