# Objective-c using UIInterfaceOrientationMask to control orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, landscape, portrait

I have an app with 4 viewcontrollers. One must be presented only in landscape mode. The other 3 can be either landscape or portrait.

In my Deployment Information area, Device Orientation, I have Upside Down, Landscape Left, and Landscape Right checked.
In Info.plist I have 3 supported Interface Orientations: Landscape Left, Landscape Right, and Portrait Top Home Button.

In my view controller where I want ONLY landscape I have:
    -(BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
        return YES;
    }

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft+UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

In the other 3 view controllers I have:
    -(BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
        return YES;
    }

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

With all of these settings:
1) The view that should only be in landscape is only in landscape, so that's good.
2) The other 3 views can be shown in landscape left, landscape right and portrait mode with the button at the top.
3) When I try to rotate the screen in the other portrait position it doesn't rotate.

So, I change the Deployment page or the Info.plist page to include that 4th choice that isn't checked. The result is that the 3 other views rotate ok, but the landscape mode view now rotates into portrait.

What do I have to do to get my first view landscape only and the other 3 to rotate any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link to control your orientation, this worked for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24928474/6438500

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Cutting and pasting the code as shown into the view controller generated 2 errors regarding use of undeclared variable appDelegate.

Comment: Here appDelegate is instance of AppDelegate. You have to create your AppDelegate instance.